# subgroups with prime factors

Tags: group-theory

The order of a group $G$ is $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are both prime. Show that all proper subgroups of $G$ are cyclic. I need help with this. I know that all the orders of subgroups divide the order of the larger group, but I do not know where to go from there.

Answer (score 3):

The order of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ must divide the order of $G$, then, if $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, its order could be only $p , q $ or 1

Observing that a group of prime order is cyclic you can prove the assert.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

What are the divisors of $pq$?

What kind of groups exist for the orders less than $pq$?

Comment: I think you mean subgroups. Certainly there are many groups of order less than $pq$ that have nothing to do with $G$.

Comment: There aren't many groups of order less than $\;pq\;$ **and** whose order is a divisor of $\;pq\;$ , as explained in the second line...

Answer (score 1):

The order of a subgroup $ H\leq G $ must divide the order $ G $. Therefore $|H|$ is either $1 $, $ p $, $ q $ or $ pq $. If $ H $ is a proper subgroup of $ G $ (that is $ H $ is not equal to $G $) then it must be the trivial group, or it must be of prime order. Show that in this case it must be cyclic.